# calculating average of grades in php

Tags: php, average

I am trying to find the average of student grades in php. I use forms to ask the user how many students, then get them to enter the grade for each student. then the average is displayed. my code is below and i can get it to work. Below is sort of what it should look like(to give you an idea of what im trying to do). I think im using the forms incorrectly but i cant quite figure out why?

```
Enter the number of students: 3
Enter grade 1: 55
Enter grade 2: 108
Invalid grade, try again
Enter grade 2: 56
Enter grade 3: 57
the average is 56.0


<?php
//GRADES AVERAGE

$sum = 0;
$average = 0;
$students = $_POST['numStudents'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];

for($i=1; $i>$students; $i++){
if($grade <0 || $grade > 0){
    echo "invalid grade, try again";
}

$sum = $sum + $grade;
$average = $sum/$i;
}
echo "the average is = $average";
?>

<form action="task19.php" method="POST">
Enter the number of students<input type="number" name="numStudents" />
<input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>

<form action="task19.php" method="POST">
Enter the grade for student <?php $i ?> <input type="number" name="grade" />
<input type="submit" value="Enter grade" />
</form>
```

Comment: is this an exercise code? i'd suggest you solve this yourself, it'll be much fulfilling in the end, trust me, anyway, you should look into arrays as well, much easier to manage those values there

Comment: Why do you open two forms and not keep on handling both inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

First, use 1 form combining the two inputs, if you send one form, the other will not be sent. Second, take a look at the following code:

```
if($grade <0 || $grade > 0){
    echo "invalid grade, try again";
}
```

This is a little bit weird :) I think you should delete it or do a more accurate expression. It grade will always be less than 0 OR greater than 0.